# Wedge product on free module

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring, let $M$ be a free module of rank $n$ over $R$ with a basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$. Suppose that $m_1,\cdots,m_n$ are elements of $M$ such that
$$m_1\wedge\cdots\wedge m_n=ce_1\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n$$
for some invertible $c\in R^{\times}$. How to show that $m_1,\cdots,m_n$ is also a basis for $M$? I can show that $m_1,\dots,m_n$ are linear independent, but I don't know show that they span $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a direct exterior algebra argument, but otherwise you can write $M\in M_n(R)$ the matrix of $(m_i)$ in the basis $(e_i)$, and notice that $c = \det(M)$.

Then it is well-know that a matrix with invertible determinant is invertible (you just have to use the usual formula with the comatrix which holds over any commutative ring), so each $e_j$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the $m_i$.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to find a argument without using matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "argument without using matrix"? Your problem is just a reformulation of the statement that an endomorphism of a finite free module is an isomorphism if and only if its determinant is a unit. In terms of exterior algebras, this is phrased as: $f:R^n \to R^n$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\bigwedge f: R \to R$ is an isomorphism.